# How do I turn scraped list items into strings in Python?

Tags: python

Edit:

Here is my actual code. I'm using BeautifulSoup to do the scraping. Once the scrape is done, I use bleach and the cleanhtml function to remove HTML code from each date entry.

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import urllib2
import bleach
import re
import datetime as dt

def cleanhtml(raw_html):

  cleanr =re.compile('<.*?>')

  cleantext = re.sub(cleanr,'', raw_html)

  return cleantext

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [("User-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US;     rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101206 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.13")]

sign_in = br.open('https://www.mturk.com/mturk/beginsignin')

br.select_form(name="signIn")
br["email"] = 'xxxx'
br["password"] = 'xxxxx'
logged_in = br.submit()

mturk = br.open("https://www.mturk.com/mturk/status")

soup = BS(mturk.read())

date_column_values_raw = soup.findAll("td", "statusDateColumnValue")

date_column_values = bleach.clean(date_column_values_raw, strip=True)

date_column_values = cleanhtml(date_column_values)
```

I'm having trouble with a Python list I've created. I have scraped a page and I have a list of dates that looks like this:

```
[
Apr 6, 2015
, 
Apr 5, 2015
, 
Apr 4, 2015
, 
Apr 3, 2015
]
```

My goal is to turn these dates into a database friendly format i.e. 2015-04-03

My issue is that as soon as I try to iterate through them in a for loop, the loop is treating each character separately instead of by line.

So, when I do:

```
for line in date_values:
   print line
```

I get:
     [

```
 A
 p
 r

 6
 ,

 2
 0
 1
 5
 ,
 ]
```

and so on... This is obviously not the desired result.

I tried line.split() on /n and 5 in the for loop and that had no effect. So my question is, once I have my scraped list, how do I turn each line of data into separate strings?

I would appreciate any insight.

Thanks!

Comment: That is not a list. It is one big string.

Comment: you are not getting a list, it is a string in itself, you should try `strng.split("\n\n")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your `date_values` "list" is not a list at all, but just a single multi-line string.

```
date_values = """[
Apr 6, 2015
, 
Apr 5, 2015
, 
Apr 4, 2015
, 
Apr 3, 2015
]"""
```

You can use `str.split()` to split that string, but not in the `for` loop -- this way, you would try to split each single character! Instead, try this list comprehension.

```
date_list = [s.strip() for s in date_values[1:-1].split("\n,")]
```

Here, `[1:-1]` gets rid of the `[` and `]`, then splits by a newline followed by comma (either alone won't work) and finally `strip`s away and whitespaces.

Or split by lines first and then take all the lines that, after stripping whitespaces, have more than one character left:

```
date_list = [s for s in map(str.strip, date_values.splitlines()) if len(s) > 1]
```

Now, `date_list` is `['Apr 6, 2015', 'Apr 5, 2015', 'Apr 4, 2015', 'Apr 3, 2015']`. You can then use, e.g. [`strptime` and `strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to re-format the dates, e.g. like this:

```
import time
for date in date_list:
    d = time.strptime(date, "%b %d, %Y")
    date2 = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", d)
    print date, "-->", date2
```

Output:

```
Apr 6, 2015 --> 2015-04-06
Apr 5, 2015 --> 2015-04-05
Apr 4, 2015 --> 2015-04-04
Apr 3, 2015 --> 2015-04-03
```

Comment: Thanks @tobias_k I tried both of your ideas and I got errors about the list object having no attribute split or splitlines

Comment: @ChrisC In that case it would _really_ be a list, but then the behaviour of your for loop does not make sense. Please show what both `type(date_values)` and `repr(date_values)` print.

Comment: type command returns list.  repr returns "[u'[\\nApr 6, 2015\\n, \\nApr 5, 2015\\n, \\nApr 4, 2015\\n, \\nApr 3, 2015\\n, ......

Comment: @ChrisC Then you have a list that _contains_ a single multi-line string. Try `date_values = date_values[0]` to extract that value, then my code should work.

Comment: is this within a for loop or beforehand?

Comment: @ChrisC Before the list comprehension. There is no loop for that part in my code. Also, note that the output in your question still makes no sense in this case. If it still not works, please add the actual code you are using into your question. Either `date_values` is not what you tell it is there has to be some code altering it before the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks @tobias_k date_values[0] then the comprehension worked!  Thanks for your time.